# I am using insert_batch() in codeigniter and I want to fetch all insert_id for my insert_batch

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am using insert_batch() in codeigniter and I want to fetch all insert_id for my insert_batch as insert_id just gives the first inserted id

Comment: Please add in your post what you have done so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in getting the last inserted ID of a query using batch insert in CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372537/error-in-getting-the-last-inserted-id-of-a-query-using-batch-insert-in-codeignit)

Comment: Count the total rows in array which you are going to insert.
`$this->db->insert_id();` This will return the first insert id.
Now you can easily find the last insert ids
Is this logic clear to you?

Comment: Thanks Ashu I have implemented this logic thanks for the commnet